# Distributed tensorflow on distributed data : synchronize workers

Tags: tensorflow

I am using distributed tensorflow for a deep model calibration.

My data is spread on different machines (every machine contains part of the data). I created different workers, each one operating on the data of a its corresponding machine.

My calibration loop looks like this :

```
while True:
    train_feed =  # my train feed
    _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
```

Now, every N steps, I want to compute the loss on my validation data set. This validation data set is also located on different machines (every machine contains a part of the whole validation data set).

So I want all my workers to compute the validation loss on the validation data of their corresponding machine, and then the chief worker to make an average of these losses.

So the chief worker has to run its own validation loss computation on its machines, wait for the other workers to do the same on their corresponding machines, and then sum and average the results.

Is there a simple manner to do this?

Comment: There's a complicated manner to do this, which involves extracting relevant functionality from `SyncReplicasOptimizer`. I also wrote a simple "Barrier" implementation, but it's not fully debugged for distributed case -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/ef407a599f0f549f62d91c3a00dcfb6c

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, taking a look